# javascript purpose of "=" in attaching function to event listener

Tags: javascript

why use the equal sign "=",  not the dot "." in attaching function to event listener since,if I'm not wrong, it is the convention in javascript to use the dot to mean the attach action.

```
clickme.onclick=function() {alert("pikachu")}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing accessing with assigning. Dot is for accessing a value, and the equal sign is for assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator is used because it's an assignment. A function reference is assigned to an object property.

The left side of the assignment is the property `onclick` in the object `clickme`. The dot is used to access the property of the object.

The right side of the assignment is a function expression, so the result is a reference to a function object. You can also declare a function and use its identifier on the right side:

```
function clickHandler() {
  alert("pikachu");
}

clickme.onclick = clickHandler;
```